# Make Stack Bar Chart Plotly Different Colors

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, plotly-python

So I'm creating a plotly bar chart that is stacked. Each of my stacks are returning the same color. I'd like them to have different colors. I'd prefer not to use plotly express in this situation. I also don't want to specify the color. I just want a vareity of colors. Here's my code:

```
  df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Country': {0: 'Europe',
  1: 'America',
  2: 'Asia',
  3: 'Europe',
  4: 'America',
  5: 'Asia',
  6: 'Europe',
  7: 'America',
  8: 'Asia',
  9: 'Europe',
  10: 'America',
  11: 'Asia'},
 'Year': {0: 2014,
  1: 2014,
  2: 2014,
  3: 2015,
  4: 2015,
  5: 2015,
  6: 2016,
  7: 2016,
  8: 2016,
  9: 2017,
  10: 2017,
  11: 2017},
 'Amount': {0: 1600,
  1: 410,
  2: 150,
  3: 1300,
  4: 300,
  5: 170,
  6: 1000,
  7: 500,
  8: 200,
  9: 900,
  10: 500,
  11: 210}})

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df2['Year'], y=df['Amount'], 
                        ))
fig.update_layout(title="Personnel at Work",
                 barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You are mimicking the code I have answered and asking the next question, but I am asking you to either accept or comment on any unacceptable aspects of my answer before asking the next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a stacked graph with a graph object, you can specify the graph as the stacking unit.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

x = [str(x) for x in df2['Year'].unique().tolist()]

for c in df2['Country'].unique():
    df3 = df2.query('Country == @c')
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=df3['Amount'], name=c))
fig.update_layout(title="Personnel at Work", barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

[image]